# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from turicreate)

Tags: python, pip, turi-create

Collecting tensorflow<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from turicreate)

**I am facing an error while installing turicreate.**

**ERROR:**
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from turicreate) (from versions: 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0rc1, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow<2.1.0,>=2.0.0 (from turicreate)

The Output of python3 -m pip debug --verbose

```
pip version: pip 20.2.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip (python 3.6)
sys.version: 3.6.9 (default, Jul 17 2020, 12:50:27) 
[GCC 8.4.0]
sys.executable: /usr/bin/python3
sys.getdefaultencoding: utf-8
sys.getfilesystemencoding: utf-8
locale.getpreferredencoding: UTF-8
sys.platform: linux
sys.implementation:
  name: cpython
'cert' config value: Not specified
REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE: None
CURL_CA_BUNDLE: None
pip._vendor.certifi.where(): /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/certifi/cacert.pem
pip._vendor.DEBUNDLED: False
vendored library versions:
  appdirs==1.4.4
  CacheControl==0.12.6
  colorama==0.4.3
  contextlib2==0.6.0.post1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  distlib==0.3.1
  distro==1.5.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  html5lib==1.1
  ipaddress==1.0.23
  msgpack==1.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  packaging==20.4
  pep517==0.8.2
  progress==1.5
  pyparsing==2.4.7
  requests==2.24.0
  certifi==2020.06.20
  chardet==3.0.4
  idna==2.10
  urllib3==1.25.9
  resolvelib==0.4.0
  retrying==1.3.3 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  setuptools==44.0.0 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
  six==1.15.0
  toml==0.10.1
  webencodings==0.5.1 (Unable to locate actual module version, using vendor.txt specified version)
Compatible tags: 69
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp36-none-linux_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp35-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp34-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp33-abi3-linux_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2014_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-manylinux1_x86_64
  cp32-abi3-linux_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py36-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py36-none-linux_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py3-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py3-none-linux_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py35-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py35-none-linux_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py34-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py34-none-linux_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py33-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py33-none-linux_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py32-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py32-none-linux_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py31-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py31-none-linux_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2014_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux2010_x86_64
  py30-none-manylinux1_x86_64
  py30-none-linux_x86_64
  cp36-none-any
  py36-none-any
  py3-none-any
  py35-none-any
  py34-none-any
  py33-none-any
  py32-none-any
  py31-none-any
  py30-none-any
```

Comment: Probably your Python interpreter is not supported for that range. What is the output of `python -m pip debug --verbose`?

Comment: There seems to be matching tags for [_tensorflow 2.0.3_](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow/2.0.3/#files) which is in range, for example [`cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64`](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/87/5e/254f5baeb331a7c9065b796d786cd07c5db79f2d76a496b74891a6521e25/tensorflow-2.0.3-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl). So it is surprising that _pip_ could not find it and install it. -- Are you sure you are using the _pip_ corresponding to your interpreter: `python3 -m pip install tensorflow`? -- You might want to try downloading and installing the _wheel_ directly.